# Who put their spacesuit boots on the wrong feet?

Tags: spacesuits, failure, eva

Was just reading Mike Massimino's memoir *Spaceman* and came across this fascinating line:

> Another time a spacewalker - and this is a true story - accidentally
>   put his right boot on his left foot and put his left boot on his right
>   foot. Once he got outside, he couldn't fit in a foot restraint.

Some searching turned up a reference to (presumably) the same incident in Clay Anderson's book [*It's a Question of Space*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wF9dDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=spacewalk%20boots%20on%20wrong%20foot&source=bl&ots=XDH5um3tx7&sig=ACfU3U1VVeiFuhy0sFp9WkknbUoCYr5yuw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv-MHGhprkAhUMna0KHZSZAMoQ6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=spacewalk%20boots%20on%20wrong%20foot&f=false).

Neither reference gives any more information.

Can anyone provide more details?

Comment: I recall seeing this claim somewhere else in the past few months.  However, I cannot recall where I saw it, and my attempts to find an answer were unsuccessful.  Sorry.

Comment: I'm more surprised that one can put a wrong boot at all. I always thought that unlike arms and gloves the "lower torso" of EMU (basically pants with boots) is a single non-separable item.

Comment: @OON No, the legs are made up of segments that can be chosen to fit different crewpersons.  "The combination of these rings, five sizes of leg assemblies, and the
adjustable leg brackets allow for many variations" (EMU systems workbook) However, I was also surprised that the boots could be attached to the wrong legs.

Comment: The legs of the pressure garment assembly for the Apollo 12 commander (Pete Conrad) were too short, and a hole developed inside the boots.  Post-flight leakage of the suit was four times that of pre-flight, although within allowable limits.  Perhaps Massimino was mistakenly thinking of this incident?

Comment: @DrSheldon unlikely. No EVA foot restraints on Apollo.

Comment: If there's still interest, I could volunteer to ask Mike...but I hate to bother him for trivial stuff - he's pretty busy these days.  I'm assuming that this incident probably took place @ the NBL...

Comment: @Digger when does your memoir come out? :) You were featured in his! (all good).

Comment: @OrganicMarble I get asked about a book often, but I've been too lazy to take on another project...btw, Mike just got back w/ me - indeed, it was Rex. So, your answer below stands...good detective work!

Comment: Is `failure` really a good tag for this question?  After all, the EVA was successful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe not the only time...

..but one time was [Rex Walheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rex_J._Walheim), on STS-122.  Surprisingly, it was on the third EVA of the mission, and the fifth EVA of his career.

[image]

(Original NASA image from [https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/s122e008916/s122e008916~orig.jpg](https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/s122e008916/s122e008916%7Eorig.jpg)) Caption reads

> S122-E-008915 (15 Feb. 2008) --- Astronaut Rex Walheim, mission
> specialist, translates along the outside of the Columbus laboratory,
> the newest piece of hardware on the International Space Station.
> Astronaut Stanley Love (out of frame), mission specialist, shared this
> final period of STS-122 extravehicular activity with Walheim.

[image]

(Crop by me)

Comment: Yes it was Rex. He was a good sport about it, even though we had this picture blown up to billboard size and had it hanging outside our office.