# How big are Extravehicular Mobility Unit (EMU) boots?

Tags: iss, astronauts, eva

How big are Extravehicular Mobility Unit (EMU) boots? Are any NASA equipment related to the ISS open to the public, if so were where would I find it?

Comment: What do you mean by equipment being open to the public?

Comment: Equipment specifications that contain dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boots come in two sizes (large and small) and there are three sizing inserts for a total of six possible sizes.

> The Enhanced Boot (Figure 3.5.5) consists of a fabric
> ankle joint, fabric foot envelope, fiberglass sole stiffener,
> removable heel, threaded fabric attachment ring, and a
> TMG. The Boot Assembly provides for flexion and
> extension of the ankle joint while maintaining SSA
> pressure integrity and joint shape. Two sizes of boots and
> three sizes of Boot Sizing Inserts for each of them, allow
> for sizing adaptation to different sizes of crew foot size.

much more detail available at the source https://www.lpi.usra.edu/lunar/constellation/NASA-EMU-Data-Book-JSC-E-DAA-TN55224.pdf

[image]

[image]

[image]

Acronymology

- TMG Thermal Micrometeroid Garment
- SSA Space Suit Assembly

Comment: they also come in [two chiralities](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39677/12102)